# SQLAlchemy: cascade delete

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I must be missing something trivial with SQLAlchemy's cascade options because I cannot get a simple cascade delete to operate correctly -- if a parent element is a deleted, the children persist, with `null` foreign keys.

I've put a concise test case here:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    parentid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Parent.id))
    parent = relationship(Parent, cascade = "all,delete", backref = "children")

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

session = Session()

parent = Parent()
parent.children.append(Child())
parent.children.append(Child())
parent.children.append(Child())

session.add(parent)
session.commit()

print "Before delete, children = {0}".format(session.query(Child).count())
print "Before delete, parent = {0}".format(session.query(Parent).count())

session.delete(parent)
session.commit()

print "After delete, children = {0}".format(session.query(Child).count())
print "After delete parent = {0}".format(session.query(Parent).count())

session.close()
```

Output:

```
Before delete, children = 3
Before delete, parent = 1
After delete, children = 3
After delete parent = 0
```

There is a simple, one-to-many relationship between Parent and Child. The script creates a parent, adds 3 children, then commits. Next, it deletes the parent, but the children persist. Why? How do I make the children cascade delete?

Comment: This section in the docs (at least now, 3 years later after the original post) seems quite helpful on this: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#cascades

Comment: I think the `session.commit()` after `session.delete(parent)` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 278, accepted):

The problem is that sqlalchemy considers `Child` as the parent, because that is where you defined your relationship (it doesn't care that you called it "Child" of course).

If you define the relationship on the `Parent` class instead, it will work:

```
children = relationship("Child", cascade="all,delete", backref="parent")
```

(note `"Child"` as a string: this is allowed when using the declarative style, so that you are able to refer to a class that is not yet defined)

You might want to add `delete-orphan` as well (`delete` causes children to be deleted when the parent gets deleted, `delete-orphan` also deletes any children that were "removed" from the parent, even if the parent is not deleted)

EDIT: just found out: if you *really* want to define the relationship on the `Child` class, you can do so, but you will have to define the cascade **on the backref** (by creating the backref explicitly), like this:

```
parent = relationship(Parent, backref=backref("children", cascade="all,delete"))
```

(implying `from sqlalchemy.orm import backref`)

Comment: This is well explained in the current doc http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/cascades.html

Comment: @Steven - can you please explain what "removed from parent" means?

Comment: @Lyman Zerga: in the OP's example: if you remove a `Child` object from `parent.children`, should that object be deleted from the database, or should only it's reference to the parent be removed (ie. set `parentid` column to null, instead of deleting the row)

Comment: Wait, the `relationship` doesn't dictate the parent-child setup. Using `ForeignKey` on a table is what sets it up as the child. It doesn't matter if the `relationship` is on the parent or child.

Comment: just a note, for `cascade` in `relation`, you need to add it to the parent table, NOT the child table.

Answer (score 192):

Pretty old post, but I just spent an hour or two on this, so I wanted to share my finding, especially since some of the other comments listed aren't quite right.

### TL;DR

Give the child table a foreign or modify the existing one, adding `ondelete='CASCADE'`:

```
parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parent.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
```

And *one* of the following relationships:

a) This on the parent table:

```
children = db.relationship('Child', backref='parent', passive_deletes=True)
```

b) *Or* this on the child table:

```
parent = db.relationship('Parent', backref=backref('children', passive_deletes=True))
```

---

### Details

First off, despite what the accepted answer says, the parent/child relationship is not established by using `relationship`, it's established by using `ForeignKey`. You can put the `relationship` on either the parent or child tables and it will work fine. Although, apparently on the child tables, you have to use the `backref` function in addition to the keyword argument.

#### Option 1 (preferred)

Second, SqlAlchemy supports two different kinds of cascading. The first, and the one I recommend, is built into your database and usually takes the form of a constraint on the foreign key declaration. In PostgreSQL it looks like this:

```
CONSTRAINT child_parent_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
REFERENCES parent_table(id) MATCH SIMPLE
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

This means that when you delete a record from `parent_table`, then all the corresponding rows in `child_table` will be deleted for you by the database. It's fast and reliable and probably your best bet. You set this up in SqlAlchemy through `ForeignKey` like this (part of the child table definition):

```
parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parent.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
parent = db.relationship('Parent', backref=backref('children', passive_deletes=True))
```

The `ondelete='CASCADE'` is the part that creates the `ON DELETE CASCADE` on the table.

#### Gotcha!

There's an important caveat here. Notice how I have a `relationship` specified with `passive_deletes=True`? If you don't have that, the entire thing will not work. This is because by default when you delete a parent record SqlAlchemy does something really weird. It sets the foreign keys of all child rows to `NULL`. So if you delete a row from `parent_table` where `id` = 5, then it will basically execute

```
UPDATE child_table SET parent_id = NULL WHERE parent_id = 5
```

Why you would want this I have no idea. I'd be surprised if many database engines even allowed you to set a valid foreign key to `NULL`, creating an orphan. Seems like a bad idea, but maybe there's a use case. Anyway, if you let SqlAlchemy do this, you will prevent the database from being able to clean up the children using the `ON DELETE CASCADE` that you set up. This is because it relies on those foreign keys to know which child rows to delete. Once SqlAlchemy has set them all to `NULL`, the database can't delete them. Setting the `passive_deletes=True` prevents SqlAlchemy from `NULL`ing out the foreign keys.

You can read more about passive deletes in the [SqlAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/large_collections.html#using-passive-deletes).

#### Option 2

The other way you can do it is to let SqlAlchemy do it for you. This is set up using the `cascade` argument of the `relationship`. If you have the relationship defined on the parent table, it looks like this:

```
children = relationship('Child', cascade='all,delete', backref='parent')
```

If the relationship is on the child, you do it like this:

```
parent = relationship('Parent', backref=backref('children', cascade='all,delete'))
```

Again, this is the child so you have to call a method called `backref` and putting the cascade data in there.

With this in place, when you delete a parent row, SqlAlchemy will actually run delete statements for you to clean up the child rows. This will likely not be as efficient as letting this database handle if for you so I don't recommend it.

Here are the [SqlAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/cascades.html?highlight=cascade#delete) on the cascading features it supports.

Comment: Why does declaring a `Column` in the child table as `ForeignKey('parent.id', ondelete='cascade', onupdate='cascade')` not work, either? I expected the children to be deleted when their parent table row got deleted too. Instead, SQLA either sets the children to a `parent.id=NULL` or leaves them "as is", but no deletes. That's after originally defining the `relationship` in the parent as `children = relationship('Parent', backref='parent')` or `relationship('Parent', backref=backref('parent', passive_deletes=True))`; DB shows `cascade` rules in the DDL (SQLite3-based proof-of-concept). Thoughts?

Comment: Also, I should note that when I use `backref=backref('parent', passive_deletes=True)` I get the following warning: `SAWarning: On Parent.children, 'passive_deletes' is normally configured on one-to-many, one-to-one, many-to-many relationships only.
  "relationships only." % self`, suggesting it doesn't like the use of `passive_deletes=True` in this (obvious) one-to-many parent-child relationship for some reason.

Comment: Great explanation. One question - is `delete` redundant in `cascade='all,delete'` ?

Comment: @zaggi `delete` IS redundant in `cascade='all,delete'`, since according to the [SQLAlchemy's docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/cascades.html#cascades), `all` is a synonym for: `save-update, merge, refresh-expire, expunge, delete`

Comment: @pmsoltani I don't think it is redundant since it is heavily used in the docs: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/cascades.html#using-delete-cascade-with-many-to-many-relationships.

Comment: Thanks for the Gotcha part. Just what pawned me. This answer probably deserves to be accepted.

Comment: I got the same condition as setting `relationship('child',backref='parent', cascade="all, delete", passive_deletes=True)` and `Column(..., ForeignKey('parent.id', ondelete="CASCADE"))` and still don't work, when I try to delete the parent row the child row FK are set to NULL. I add `nullable=False` in the child FK column as  `Column(..., ForeignKey('parent.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)` and it works, not sure if this is the reason why cannot delete the child row.

Comment: Also read about `passive_deletes="all"` behaviour

Comment: @d512, please add `cascade="all, delete"` to the relationship to handle the case where some children are loaded. The [current docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/cascades.html#using-foreign-key-on-delete-cascade-with-orm-relationships) are quite clear about that.
Without that I still get the children's `parent_id` set to `null`.

Answer (score 173):

@Steven's asnwer is good when you are deleting through `session.delete()` which never happens in my case. I noticed that most of the time I delete through `session.query().filter().delete()` (which doesn't put elements in the memory and deletes directly from db).
Using this method sqlalchemy's `cascade='all, delete'` doesn't work. There is a solution though: `ON DELETE CASCADE` through db (note: not all databases support it).

```
class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "children"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("parents.id", ondelete='CASCADE'))

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parents"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child = relationship(Child, backref="parent", passive_deletes=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this difference - I was trying to use `session.query().filter().delete()` and struggling to find the issue

Comment: I had to set `passive_deletes='all'` in order to get the children to be deleted by the database cascade when the parent is deleted. With `passive_deletes=True`, children objects were getting disassociated (parent set to NULL) before the parent is deleted, so the database cascade wasn't doing anything.

Comment: @MiloradPop-Tosic I haven't used SQLAlchemy for over 3 years but reading [the doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/collections.html#passive-deletes) looks like passive_deletes=True is still the right thing.

Comment: I can confirm that `passive_deletes=True` does work correctly in this scenario.

Comment: I was having trouble with alembic auto-generating revisions that included cascade on delete - this was the answer.

Comment: @MiloradPop-Tosic Your comment was the only thing that fixed this for me, I wish it was an answer that I could upvote

Comment: To impart more clarity to this answer (and some follow-up comments), the syntax `session.query(Parent).filter().delete()` will always work if you set `ondelete='cascade'` on the child's foreign key declaration (i.e. the cascade rules are specified directly at the database level). This works whether or not `passive_delete` has been declared on the relationship (i.e. at the orm level) because the query is an actual sql `DELETE`. The object is not first loaded to then be deleted later with `session.delete(parent)`, so the orm is never involved.

Comment: On the other hand, if you delete a parent using `session.delete(parent)` (meaning first loading an object then deleting it with the orm), then the orm mechanism needs to know (1) if it should be involved in the cascade to children objects and in that case, (2) how it should handle it (set null, delete, restrict). `passive_delete` addresses (1) and is particularly useful in situations where you already have foreign key rules set at the db level and wish to let the db handle cascades.

Comment: Because I ended up at this answer three times now while getting the deletes done: For SQLite it is vital to enable foreign_keys. In short: `cursor.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON')` -- using `event.listens_for` as explained in https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sqlite.html#sqlite-foreign-keys (edit: and explained in another answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62327279)

Comment: Wish I could upvote this answer more than once - it took me waaaay too long to figure out that `x = session.query(T).all(); [session.delete(y) for y in x]` is not the same as `session.query(T).delete()`.  It's particularly non-obvious when using flask_sqlalchemy, which gives you `T.query.delete()` which really looks like it _should_ take into account the relationships for some reason.

Comment: And now in 2.0 they are deprecating `session.query` and showing `session.execute` as [the alternative](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_20.html#migration-orm-usage).

Comment: if you are using session.query, this is the ANSWER. saved my bacon. thank you!!!

Comment: You should add `cascade="all, delete"` to handle the case where some children are loaded. @DhhJmm pointed to the problem already, but [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/cascades.html#using-foreign-key-on-delete-cascade-with-orm-relationships) say you should add `cascade="all, delete"` not use `passive_deletes='all'`.

Answer (score 9):

Alex Okrushko answer almost worked best for me. Used ondelete='CASCADE' and passive_deletes=True combined. But I had to do something extra to make it work for sqlite.

```
Base = declarative_base()
ROOM_TABLE = "roomdata"
FURNITURE_TABLE = "furnituredata"

class DBFurniture(Base):
    __tablename__ = FURNITURE_TABLE
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    room_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('roomdata.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))


class DBRoom(Base):
    __tablename__ = ROOM_TABLE
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    furniture = relationship("DBFurniture", backref="room", passive_deletes=True)
```

Make sure to add this code to ensure it works for sqlite.

```
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlite3 import Connection as SQLite3Connection

@event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
def _set_sqlite_pragma(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    if isinstance(dbapi_connection, SQLite3Connection):
        cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;")
        cursor.close()
```

Stolen from here: [SQLAlchemy expression language and SQLite's on delete cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726047/sqlalchemy-expression-language-and-sqlites-on-delete-cascade)

Answer (score 7):

Steven is correct in that you need to explicitly create the backref, this results in the cascade being applied on the parent (as opposed to it being applied to the child like in the test scenario).

However, defining the relationship on the Child does NOT make sqlalchemy consider Child the parent. It doesn't matter where the relationship is defined (child or parent), its the foreign key that links the two tables that determines which is the parent and which is the child.

It makes sense to stick to one convention though, and based on Steven's response, I'm defining all my child relationships on the parent.

Answer (score 7):

Steven's answer is solid.  I'd like to point out an additional implication.

By using `relationship`, you're making the app layer (Flask) responsible for referential integrity. That means other processes that access the database not through Flask, like a database utility or a person connecting to the database directly, will not experience those constraints and could change your data in a way that breaks the logical data model you worked so hard to design.

Whenever possible, use the `ForeignKey` approach described by d512 and Alex. The DB engine is very good at truly enforcing constraints (in an unavoidable way), so this is by far the best strategy for maintaining data integrity.  The only time you need to rely on an app to handle data integrity is when the database can't handle them, e.g. versions of SQLite that don't support foreign keys.

If you need to create further linkage among entities to enable app behaviors like navigating parent-child object relationships, use `backref` in conjunction with `ForeignKey`.

Answer (score 6):

I struggled with the documentation as well, but found that the docstrings themselves tend to be easier than the manual.  For example, if you import relationship from sqlalchemy.orm and do help(relationship), it will give you all the options you can specify for cascade.  The bullet for `delete-orphan` says:

> if an item of the child's type with no parent is detected, mark it for deletion.
>   Note that this option prevents a pending item of the child's class from being
>   persisted without a parent present.

I realize your issue was more with the way the documentation for defining parent-child relationships.  But it seemed that you might also be having a problem with the cascade options, because `"all"` includes `"delete"`.  `"delete-orphan"` is the only option that's not included in `"all"`.

Comment: Using `help(..)` on the `sqlalchemy` objects helps a lot! Thanks :-))) ! PyCharm shows nothing in context docks, and plainly forgot to check the `help`. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Even tho this question is very old, it comes up first when searched for in Google so I'll post my solution to add up to what others said (I've spent few hours even after reading all the answers in here).

As d512 explained, it is all about Foreign Keys. It was quite a surprise to me but not all databases / engines support Foreign Keys. I'm running a MySQL database. After long investigation, I noticed that when I create new table it defaults to an engine (MyISAM) that doesn't support Foreign Keys. All I had to do was to set it to InnoDB by adding `mysql_engine='InnoDB'` when defining a Table. In my project I'm using an imperative mapping and it looks like so:

```
db.Table('child',
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    # other columns
    Column('parent_id',
           ForeignKey('parent.id', ondelete="CASCADE")),
    mysql_engine='InnoDB')
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer by Stevan is perfect. But if you are still getting the error. Other possible try on top of that would be -

http://vincentaudebert.github.io/python/sql/2015/10/09/cascade-delete-sqlalchemy/

Copied from the link-

Quick tip if you get in trouble with a foreign key dependency even if you have specified a cascade delete in your models.

Using SQLAlchemy, to specify a cascade delete you should have `cascade='all, delete'` on your parent table. Ok but then when you execute something like:

```
session.query(models.yourmodule.YourParentTable).filter(conditions).delete()
```

It actually triggers an error about a foreign key used in your children tables.

The solution I used it to query the object and then delete it:

```
session = models.DBSession()
your_db_object = session.query(models.yourmodule.YourParentTable).filter(conditions).first()
if your_db_object is not None:
    session.delete(your_db_object)
```

This should delete your parent record AND all the children associated with it.

Comment: Is calling `.first()` required? What filter conditions return a list of objects, and everything has to be deleted? Isn't calling `.first()` gets only the first object? @Prashant

Comment: I've come across exactly this problem. I would like to clear my whole table in pytest fixture, but `session.query(Parent).delete()` doesn't seem to be working with foreign keys. Querying object and then iterating through each on separately doesn't seem to be the correct solution, at least it shouldn't be....

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:** If the above solutions don't work, try adding nullable=False to your column.

I'd like to add a small point here for some people who may not get the cascade function to work with the existing solutions (which are great). The main difference between my work and the example was that I used automap. I do not know exactly how that might interfere with the setup of cascades, but I want to note that I used it. I am also working with a SQLite database.

I tried every solution described here, but rows in my child table continued to have their foreign key set to null when the parent row was deleted. I'd tried all the solutions here to no avail. However, the cascade worked once I set the child column with the foreign key to nullable = False.

On the child table, I added:

```
Column('parent_id', Integer(), ForeignKey('parent.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)
Child.parent = relationship("parent", backref=backref("children", passive_deletes=True)
```

With this setup, the cascade functioned as expected.

Comment: I also use automap and only setting the `nullable=False` that I can delete the child rows.

Comment: Don’t write "the above solutions" because the order in which answers appear can vary. All the answers above yours are more recent, so I believe you refer to the ones below.