# Deleting two relational table values in single view function in flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to delete two table values in one view function in flask.

```
class SampleOrder(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'sample_orders'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    customer_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("customers.id"))
    date = db.Column(db.Date,nullable=False,default = datetime.date)
    code = db.Column(db.String,nullable=False,unique=True)
    sample_item = db.relationship('SampleOrderItem',backref='sample_orders')

    def __init__(self,customer_id,date,code):
        self.customer_id = customer_id
        self.date = date
        self.code = code


class SampleOrderItem(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    item_code = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey(Item.code))
    season_code = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey(Season.code))
    qty = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    unit_code = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey(Unit.code))
    order_code = db.Column(db.String,db.ForeignKey(SampleOrder.code))

    def __init__(self,item_code,season_code,qty,unit_code,order_code):
        self.item_code = item_code.code
        self.season_code = season_code.code
        self.qty = qty
        self.unit_code = unit_code.code
        self.order_code = order_code
```

when I delete SampleOrder, I also want to delete SampleOrderItems related with it.

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033547/sqlalchemy-cascade-delete

Comment: @gittert Thanks You so much it worked. : )