# ON_DELETE="CASCADE" does not work with flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, cascading-deletes

I am developing a WebApp in flask and using flask-sqlalchemy to define my Models and store them in an SQLite database. In short, I have the following 3 models (A Porject can have multiple files, and each file can have multiple results):

```py
class Project(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    files = db.relationship("File", backref="project", passive_deletes=True)

class File(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    path = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    project_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey("project.id", ondelete="CASCADE"),
        nullable=False)

    results = db.relationship("Result", backref="file", passive_deletes=True)

class Result(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    file_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey("file.id", ondelete="CASCADE"),
        nullable=False)
```

Now the problem is, that when I create a project, create and assign some files to the project, create some results and assign them to some files, and finally **delete** the project, the cascade deleting of the files and the results does not work. I found the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033547/sqlalchemy-cascade-delete) and implemented the `db.relationship` attributes as suggested there, but the problem remains the same.

P.S.: here is a [minimal working example](https://gist.github.com/DiKorsch/2dfb47ba31907d9b8f7d7dd8f757685e), that shows the problem.

P.P.S.: Can somebody confirm, that the problem is reproducible. Not that it only happens on my computer/my environment.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#foreign-key-support

Comment: ohhh... I see... I have to register this listener, so that for EVERY connection this pragma is executed >.<

Answer (score 0):

Well, this answer goes in the category [RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM). As Gord Thompson "mentioned" with the link to the documentary of sqlalchemy, one needs to add the following lines somewhere reachable on flask app start:

```py
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy import event

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
def set_sqlite_pragma(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON")
    cursor.close()
```

(now I am asking myself, why not a single word is written about this in the [flask-sqlalchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/#simple-relationships) docu :-/ )