# cascade delete not being used sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am getting the following error when I try to delete all entries from `parent` table

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation) update or delete on table "parent" violates foreign key constraint "child_p_id_fkey" on table "child"
> DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "child".

This is my code, and I have already tried adding `cascade`in either ends of `relationship` as per [SQLAlchemy: cascade delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033547/sqlalchemy-cascade-delete), in which case I get this instead

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: For many-to-one relationship Child.parent, delete-orphan cascade is normally configured only on the "one" side of a one-to-many relationship, and not on the "many" side of a many-to-one or many-to-many relationship.  To force this relationship to allow a particular "Parent" object to be referred towards by only a single "Child" object at a time via the Child.parent relationship, which would allow delete-orphan cascade to take place in this direction, set the single_parent=True flag. (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/bbf0)

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, delete
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship, Session

Base = declarative_base()

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship(
        "Child",
        back_populates="parent",
        cascade="save-update, merge, delete, delete-orphan",
    )

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    p_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Parent.id))
    parent = relationship(Parent, back_populates="children")


engine = create_engine(
    "postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/postgres", future=True
)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session, session.begin():
    foo = Parent()
    session.add(foo)
    session.add(Child(parent=foo))

with Session(engine) as session:
    session.execute(delete(Parent).where(Parent.id == 1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it when you use something like `delete` directly you step outside the orm.  For the relationship cascades to execute you need to use `session.delete(foo)`.

#### ORM DELETE

So in your last block you'd need to do something like this to trigger the cascades in your `relationship` on `Parent`:

```py
with Session(engine) as session:
    # Select the parent back from the db
    foo = session.get(Parent, 1)
    # Now delete it with the ORM
    session.delete(foo)
```

#### BULK DELETE / CORE DELETE

To cascade when using `session.execute(delete(Parent).where(Parent.id == 1))` you need to set `ondelete='CASCADE'` on the foreign key like this:

```py
class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    p_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Parent.id, ondelete='CASCADE'))
    parent = relationship(Parent, back_populates="children")
```

Combining `relationship(..., cascade="...")` and `ondelete=...` together is explained here:

[using-foreign-key-on-delete-cascade-with-orm-relationships](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/cascades.html#using-foreign-key-on-delete-cascade-with-orm-relationships)

Comment: I wanted a bulk delete and your solution works, just a quick follow up, do I need to setup some alembic migration if I add `ondelete='CASCADE'` to my column? or that only applies in python land and no migration is needed?

Comment: @Valerie Yes you will need to drop the existing foreign key and then recreate it.  I don't think you need to change the column itself.  Lookup the constraint name of the foreign key on the `Child` table, then use `op.drop_constraint` to drop that constraint and then use `op.create_foreign_key` to recreate it but this time set [`ondelete`](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.create_foreign_key.params.ondelete).  I think that should work.