# Python FastAPI SQLAlchemy CASCADE not working

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have the following code, `UserModel` has a one-to-one relationship with `UserAdditionalDetailsModel`, now when I delete a user, the associated/linked `UserAdditionalDetailsModel` gets automatically deleted/cascaded as it should.

Similarly I have set up cascade on `ResourceModel` and `AssignmentModel`, now when I try to delete a ``CourseModel``` object, I get an error specifying that there is a FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT FAILED.

Why are the associated `ResourceModel` and `AssignmentModel` objects not being deleted automatically? Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

Also I could have attached the error thread, but there is no useful information in there other than FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINED failed, it's not even telling where it fails.

Please help. TIA.

```
student_course_association_table = Table(
    "student_course_association_table",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("user_id", Integer, ForeignKey("users.id")),
    Column("course_id", Integer, ForeignKey("courses.id")),
)


class UserModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    first_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    last_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    is_admin = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)

    # Define the one-to-one relationship with UserAdditionalDetailsModel
    additional_details = relationship(
        "UserAdditionalDetailsModel", uselist=False, cascade="all,delete"
    )
    # Define the many-to-many relationship with CourseModel
    courses = relationship(
        "CourseModel",
        secondary=student_course_association_table,
    )

    created_at = Column(
        DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=True, server_default=func.now()
    )
    updated_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=True, onupdate=func.now())

    def update(self, user: UserUpdateClass, **kwargs):
        self.first_name = user.first_name
        self.last_name = user.last_name
        self.email = user.email

    def update_password(self, new_password: str, **kwargs):
        self.password = new_password


class UserAdditionalDetailsModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_additional_details"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"), unique=True, nullable=False)
    bio = Column(Text, nullable=True, default=None)
    phone = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=True, default=None)
    address = Column(String, nullable=True, default=None)
    profile_picture_link = Column(String, nullable=True, default=None)
    facebook_profile = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=True, default=None)
    instagram_profile = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=True, default=None)

    def update(self, user: UserUpdateClass, **kwargs):
        self.bio = user.additional_details.bio
        self.phone = user.additional_details.phone
        self.address = user.additional_details.address
        self.profile_picture_link = user.additional_details.profile_picture_link
        self.facebook_profile = user.additional_details.facebook_profile
        self.instagram_profile = user.additional_details.instagram_profile

    def update_profile_picture_link(self, profile_picture_link: str, **kwargs):
        self.profile_picture_link = profile_picture_link


class CourseLevelModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "course_levels"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    description = Column(Text, nullable=False)

    def update(self, course_level: CourseLevelCreateOrUpdate, **kwargs):
        self.title = course_level.title
        self.description = course_level.description


class CourseModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "courses"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    description = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    image_link = Column(String, nullable=False)
    course_level_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("course_levels.id"), nullable=False)

    # Define the one-to-one relationship with CourseLevelModel
    course_level = relationship("CourseLevelModel", uselist=False, cascade="none")
    # Define the one-to-many relationship with ResourceModel
    resources = relationship(
        "ResourceModel", back_populates="course", cascade="all,delete"
    )
    # # Define the one-to-many relationship with AssignmentModel
    assignments = relationship(
        "AssignmentModel", back_populates="course", cascade="all,delete"
    )

    created_at = Column(
        DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=True, server_default=func.now()
    )
    updated_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=True, onupdate=func.now())

    def update(self, course: CourseCreateOrUpdateClass, **kwargs):
        self.title = course.title
        self.description = course.description
        self.image_link = course.image_link
        self.course_level_id = course.course_level_id

    def update_image_link(self, image_link: str, **kwargs):
        self.image_link = image_link


class ResourceModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "resources"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    resource_link = Column(String, nullable=False)
    resource_type = Column(Enum(AcceptedTypesEnum, nullable=False))
    course_id = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey("courses.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False
    )

    # Define a many-to-one relationship with CourseModel
    course = relationship("CourseModel", back_populates="resources")

    created_at = Column(
        DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=True, server_default=func.now()
    )
    updated_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=True, onupdate=func.now())

    def update(self, resource: ResourceTitleUpdateClass, **kwargs):
        self.title = resource.title

    def update_resource_link_and_type(
        self, resource_link: str, resource_type: str, **kwargs
    ):
        self.resource_link = resource_link
        self.resource_type = resource_type


class AssignmentModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "assignments"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    description = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    resource_link = Column(String, nullable=False)
    resource_type = Column(Enum(AcceptedTypesEnum, nullable=False))
    course_id = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey("courses.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False
    )

    # Define a many-to-one relationship with CourseModel
    course = relationship("CourseModel", back_populates="assignments")

    created_at = Column(
        DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=True, server_default=func.now()
    )
    updated_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=True, onupdate=func.now())

    def update(self, assignment: AssignentUpdateClass, **kwargs):
        self.title = assignment.title
        self.description = assignment.description

    def update_resource_link_and_type(
        self, resource_link: str, resource_type: str, **kwargs
    ):
        self.resource_link = resource_link
        self.resource_type = resource_type
```

Comment: Okay, so what I noticed was the the foreign key constrained is only triggered when the a student is associated with that particular course,possibly it is triggered when we are trying to delete a course, and ```student_course_association_table``` has a reference to it.

Comment: you can find your answer on this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033547/sqlalchemy-cascade-delete)